# Hoare partition not working when more than one value is equal to pivot

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, hoare-logic

I'm trying to write my own hoare partition function to better understand it. I thought I followed its definition and pseudo-code well but even though it seems to work as expected on many occasions, it falls apart and goes into infinite loop when a list with multiple values equal to pivot are passed in. Where is my mistake, how should I modify this to fix the bug?

```
def partition(lst, left_index, right_index):
    pivot = lst[right_index]


    while True:
        #Increment left index until value at that index is greater or equal to pivot
        while True:
            if lst[left_index] >= pivot: break
            left_index += 1

        #Increment right index until value at that index is less or equal to pivot
        while True:
            if lst[right_index] <= pivot: break
            right_index -= 1

        if left_index < right_index:
            lst[left_index], lst[right_index] = lst[right_index], lst[left_index]
        else:
            return right_index

return partition(0, end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing for equality with pivot value in both `lst[left_index] >= pivot` and `lst[right_index] <= pivot`. This effectively prevents both indices from skipping over pivot-valued elements. Therefore, when two or more pivot-valued elements are pushed toward the middle of your list, `left_index` and `right_index` get separated by an unsurmountable barrier. Delete the equal sign in one of those `break`ing lines, and the non-halting problem will be gone.

However, as a result of this change the loop that moves `left_index` may push it by one position above `right_index` and even go out of bounds when `right_index` stays at its initial position. Similarly, the loop that moves `right_index` may push it by one position below `left_index` and even go out of bounds when `left_index` stays at its initial position. To prevent that from happening you must change `while True:` in those loops to `while left_index < right_index:`.

Note that the partitioning will be slightly different depending on whether you remove the equality check for `left_index` or `right_index`. It matters for the boundary cases, when the pivot element turns out to be the smallest or the largest value in the list. Taking into account that in the beginning `right_index` represents an internal position with respect to the input range and `left_index` points to a boundary position, you must allow `left_index` to skip over pivot values whereas `right_index` must be instructed to stop at pivot values (the opposite logic would enable `left_index` staying at its initial position till the end of the algorithm, while `right_index` could be pushed all the way down to `left_index`, producing no partitioning whatsoever).

Thus the corrected code will be this:

```
def partition(lst, left_index, right_index):
    pivot = lst[right_index]

    while True:
        while left_index < right_index and lst[left_index] <= pivot:
            left_index += 1

        while left_index < right_index and lst[right_index] > pivot:
            right_index -= 1

        if left_index < right_index:
            lst[left_index], lst[right_index] = lst[right_index], lst[left_index]
        else:
            return right_index
```

Comment: Hmmm... Even though after removing equal sign it no longer goes into infinite loop it still doesn't partition list properly... it even seems that the cases which worked well previously no longer do with this change :D Uchhh, could you give my code a deeper look as from this I think I may have made some mistakes in the very basics of the algo implementation... Thanks ^^